# Styling jsPlumb outline using CSS

Tags: css, jsplumb

We are using “Styling via CSS” to style connectors, however the color in the css seems to overwrite both the outline color and the connector color. The selector we are using is as follows:

```
svg.fs-connector path {
    stroke: lightgray;
    fill: lightgray;
    stroke-width: 3;
}

svg.fs-connector-hover path {
    stroke: gray;
    fill: gray;
    stroke-width: 3;
}
```

where fs-connector and fs-connector-hover are the cssClass’es we assign when creating the endpoints.

Is there any way for the css selector to target the svg path of the connector and its overlay (the arrow), but leave the outline svg path as the original color as specified in defaults (or even better, is there a way to style the outline color separately)?

Comment: can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the issue ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/01z5sknq/2/

If you uncomment the css, you will see that the black connector with white outline will get replaced by a green connector with green outline, so basically the connector stroke width becomes the width of the connector plus the width of the outline, and you no longer get the nice “break” where they cross over (which is what the outline color gives you)

Comment: Apologies - use this version instead - https://jsfiddle.net/01z5sknq/5/

Answer (score 0):

jsPlumb current version (1.7.4) implements outlineColor and outlineWidth properties of PaintStyle for connectors by drawing two identical SVG pathes one on top of another with the different stroke and stroke-width styles ([see line 11571](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/js/dom.jsPlumb-1.7.4.js)). These path elements belong to one svg element with class, like 'fs-connector' in your case, see picture below:

[image: screenshot]

So you can apply stroke and stroke-width properties to both pathes at a time. Answer to your question 'Is there a way to style the outline color separately?' - using CSS styling, you can not.